# How to manually trigger a key press event with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got in my Vue project a Balkan Orgchart that displays a pretty cool chart that has an option to go "fullscreen" but now I added a button that opens a modal (vuedal) window when pressed. The problem is that I can't see the modal window when the chart is in fullscreen, so I wanted to force the press of the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key so the user will get out of the fullscreen mode before opening the modal window.

That's why I wanted to manually trigger the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key press event when the user tries to open the modal window.

Any clue?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you may not need to exit fullscreen mode. Consider playing around with different levels of z-index (e.g. z-index: 9999) for the modal window to raise it to the very front

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve the original event of pressing esc key, you can emit the keydown event with the keycode of the esc key. which is 27.

```
$emit('keydown', { ...e, keyCode: 27 })
```

Comment: it does not work, what does "...e"?

Comment: ."..e" is spreading the event, and then you add keyCode 27 which is the keycode of esc. So its an event of pressing esc key.